# Search and update status found/not excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm trying find a text from a table column and search it the next sheet. Then accordingly have to update the status Found/Not Found. I'm trying the below code

```html
Sub test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim rpt As Worksheet, src As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, rfnd As Range

Set rpt = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Search")
Set src = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("List")
   
Set rng = Range("Srch[Search For]")
  
For Each cell In rng
     r = 0
     rslt = ""
     a = cell.Value
     Set rslt = Nothing
     src.Select
On Error Resume Next
Set rfnd = Cells.Find(What:=a, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rfnd Is Nothing Then
    r = ActiveCell.Row
    rslt = Cells(r, 5).Value
ElseIf rfnd Is Nothing Then
rslt = "Not Found"
End If

rpt.Activate
cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = rslt

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      
End Sub
```

However, i'm getting improper result, if we are getting the result for search then the respective rows column(5) value we need to fetch. However, instead of that the above code is giving me Not Found. Can anyone tell me why and what's wrong with the above code?

Comment: Which sheet is the range `Srch[Search For]` on?

Comment: Its in "Search" sheet